# How to connect lambda to CloudFront? AWS CDK JS

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

Code:

```
rootOriginFunc = new cloudfront.experimental.EdgeFunction(stack, 'RootOriginFunction', {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    handler: 'origin.handler',
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("./lib/lambdas"),
  });

  const lambdaFunctionAssociations = [
    {
      functionVersion: rootOriginFunc.currentVersion,
      eventType: cloudfront.LambdaEdgeEventType.ORIGIN_REQUEST,
    }
  ];

.....

....
{
    pathPattern: pathPattern,
    allowedMethods: cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.ALL,
    forwardedValues: {
      queryString: true,
      headers: ["Authorization"],
    },
    defaultTtl,
    maxTtl,
    minTtl,
    isDefaultBehavior,
    lambdaFunctionAssociations,
  };
```

Error:

```
Users/denis/Documents/projects/ok/ok-app/cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront/lib/web-distribution.ts:601
        if (a.lambdaFunction.role && a.lambdaFunction.role instanceof iam.Role && a.lambdaFunction.role.assumeRolePolicy) {
                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined
    at CloudFrontWebDistribution.toBehavior (/Users/denis/Documents/projects/ok/ok-app/cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront/lib/web-distribution.ts:601:30)
    at new CloudFrontWebDistribution (/Users/denis/Documents/projects/ok/ok-app/cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront/lib/web-distribution.ts:478:78)
    at new CdkStack (/Users/denis/Documents/projects/ok/ok-app/cdk/lib/cdk-stack.ts:68:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/denis/Documents/projects/ok/ok-app/cdk/bin/cdk.ts:7:1)
```

#### The Question

1. According to documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudfront-readme.html#lambdaedge no role needs to be provided.
2. How to provide the required role?

#### Environment

- **CDK CLI Version:** 1.116.0
- **Module Version:** 1.116.0
- **Node.js Version:** v15.3.0
- **OS:** MacOS
- **Language (Version):** Typescript 3.9.7

Comment: By the way, I recommend you upgrade your Node.js version.  v15.x is [EOL (end of life)](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LambdaFunctionAssociations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudfront.LambdaFunctionAssociation.html) should take in: lambdaFunction

```
{
  lambdaFunction: IVersion
  eventType: LambdaEdgeEventType
}
```